# Creating time series flood inundation map using NetCDF future sea level and DEM

Tags: dem, netcdf, time-series, flood

I want to design a GIS tool that visualizes flood inundation maps for future sea level rise. the data that I need to use are NetCDF of projected Sea level rise for 10-year slices and DEM. The idea is to know which area will be under water in a particular year so to assess vulnerable costal area. How can I make this time series map?

Comment: You can start by telling people which GIS system you intend to this in... Also have you tried searching this forum for "flood inundation"?

Comment: using QGIS software.